# UIImageView in UICollectionView cells not displaying

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionview, xcode-storyboard

I'm very new to iOS development, sorry for posting such a basic mistake, I just can't get my head around this.

I will tell you what I have done so far, hopefully someone can help me out here. I have not edited any code so far.

1. Add collection view controller (click and drag into main.storyboard)
2. Configure cell sizes in the attributes editor of the CollectionView
3. Drag UIImageView object onto each cell
4. Import my images into the project (drag images into sidebar and import)
5. Select each UIImageView and in attributes select the correct image

Having done this, my images display perfectly in the storyboard editor but when I run the app in the simulator it is just a blank screen with my specified background colour.

[Screenshot of editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkikO.png), [Screenshot of simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6jk8.png)

Comment: Are you sure you are using static not dynamic cells? Your controller shouldn't implement datasource collection methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the data source method after creating a collection view controller class,

```
// Defines the number of cells in a section of collection view
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return numberOfItems;
}

// Defines the cells in the collection view
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
// Gallerycell is the custom collection view cell class holds the UIImage View
    GalleryCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"GalleryCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
// getting the image 
    cell.cellImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't quite understand though - do I create a new class which is a subclass of collection view controller then put your code into its .m file? And do I need to make a class for the GalleryCell too?

Comment: Yes, You are right.. And in the gallery cell add IBOutlet for the image view and connect it with your image view in the collection view cell. Set this image in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method like above

Comment: OK I've implemented as you suggested but it's throwing an error:
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier XYZGalleryCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

Comment: Add the cell identifier in the storyboard or nib same as the identifier specified in the cellForItemAtIndexPath i.e. GalleryCell
check this link http://i.imgur.com/TAIrOri.png

Answer (score 1):

You should implement datasource methods for displaying a cell. Doesn't meter if it's static or dynamic cells.